# Laravel Adlap - Try Catch method not working when login failed

Tags: laravel, ldap

using https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel for authorization.

I am trying to make clean response to user when It logs in with LDAP.

But It doesnt catch adlap.

```
    $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

    config(['ldap.connections.default.settings.account_prefix' => '']);
    config(['ldap.connections.default.settings.username' => $request->username]);
    config(['ldap.connections.default.settings.password' => $request->password]);

   try {
    $aw = Auth::attempt($credentials);
    if ($aw) {
        $results = array('status' => 1, "message" => "Login success", "redirect" => "/");
    }

   } catch (Throwable $e) {
    $results = array('status' => 0, "message" => "Login failed");
   }
```

Here is my code above.
How can I return clean response when login failed?

it returns

```
Adldap\\Auth\\BindException(code: 49)
 Invalid credentials at /var/www/html/vendor/adldap2/adldap2/src/Auth/Guard.php:107)
```

Comment: How can I return clean response when login failed? `means?` You want in what form like a JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

```
     $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

    config(['ldap.connections.default.settings.account_prefix' => '']);
    config(['ldap.connections.default.settings.username' => $request->username]);
    config(['ldap.connections.default.settings.password' => $request->password]);

   try {
    $aw = Auth::attempt($credentials);
    if ($aw) {
        $results = array('status' => 1, "message" => "Login success", "redirect" => "/");
    }

   } catch (Exception $e) {
     $results = array('status' => 0, "message" => "Login failed");// the $result will hold the array with values if try throw any exception
   }
```